# Render between two lines of code

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash

I have a huge code execution with many loops and pre-rendering processes and I was wondering if there is a way to tell the flash player to take a little pause on the code side and do a render.

Basically I have my execusion that takes a while, and on each step I make a call to a screen and then modify the scale of a loading bar. Now the problem is that the user only sees the progress at the end, I know this is due to the fact that flash does code execution and then render, i tried to make calls to stage.invalidate to force a render but it wouldnt work until the whole execusion if finished either. Is there a way to force flash to render between two lines of code?

Comment: stage.invalidate only flags the stage for lack of better words invalid. The update will only happen on the next enterframe event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem in which my AS code would be running for a long time and the UI was getting unresponsive. So I implemented my logic as a [Green Thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads).

Check out this [link](http://blog.generalrelativity.org/actionscript-30/green-threads/) for an as3 implementation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

[UIComponent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_3.html) has a rendering "framework" built into it. All display objects extend from it.
This will allow you to optimize your code, by using the invalidate methods.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to familiarize yourself with [pseudo-threads](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html).